# Setting camera image size in Android

Tags: android, image, parameters, camera

At the moment I am attempting to set my camera on my Motorola Droid phone to take an image that matches the size of my screen (854 x 480 pixels), and I am attempting to accomplish via the parameters for the camera as such:

```
Camera.Parameters parameters = this.mCamera.getParameters();
Log.i(TAG, "CAMERA SIZE: (" + this.mCameraView.getWidth() + ", " + this.mCameraView.getHeight() + ")");
parameters.setPictureSize(this.mCameraView.getWidth(), this.mCameraView.getHeight());
this.mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
this.mCamera.takePicture(null, null, this);
```

I have my activity implement the Camera.PictureCallback method of onPictureTaken (excluding log calls), so when the takePicture method is called it runs this method:

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    //Size imageSize = camera.getParameters().getPictureSize();
    //image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height);
    this.mCameraView.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(image));
}
```

For some reason though, my camera is taking pictures in 1280 x 960.  Is this some sort of minimum size the camera can capture an image in?  From log calls I can see that the Camera's parameters are still set to have a picture size of 854 x 480, but image keeps coming out as 1280 x 960.  Am I decoding the image incorrectly, am I setting the camera's parameters incorrectly, or am I doing something else wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help you can give!

Regards, celestialorb.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes there are methods provided to get the picture sizes supported by camera.
The method the paramters class of camera which provides the supported picture sizes by camera is getSupportedPictureSizes();
Using this method, you can get the supported size by camera.
The code snippet would look like this:-

```
Camera camera = Camera.open();
Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPictureSizes();
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks
Nawab

Comment: Camera has been deprecated and replaced by Camera2 but I did not find an analogous method in the new API

Answer (score 2):

I have found the answer, apparently my own screen resolution is not a supported size for the camera.  I was not aware of the camera only being able to support certain sizes as I am programming with the 1.6 SDK.

Is there any way to retrieve the supported sizes of the camera for 1.5/1.6?