# how to get a camera's screen size

Tags: android, image-processing, bitmap, camera

I've an app that places an effect on a bitmap from a camera shot. it works fine on my Galaxy portal but when trying the app on HTC Desire the jpeg image is small. How can i set the picture size that is ultimately displayed to the full size of the screen? On the Galaxy i've used BitmapFacory.Options sample size=1, this makes the image the same size as the one captured, but on different phones this doesn't work. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the capture size and the preview size (the screen size never changes that's device specific) so I am assuming you are talking about the capture size.

You can only select a capture size that is supported by the camera [Selecting Supported Image Sizes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507771/setting-camera-image-size-in-android) so I suppose you could select the highest size that a camera supports, but if you want to normalize the size (make same on each camera) then you would have to scale the resulting image up or down dependent.

But I am wondering if this is what you are really after, or are you trying to place the image in a specific location (like the center of the captured image) and possibly scaling the overlaid image to a percentage of the captured image?

Comment: Hi, on the galaxy when you take the picture, the resulting bitmap fills the entire screen exactly how it looked in the preview before pressing the takepic button. on the htc you can take a picture but the resulting bitmap is about 1/3 of the screen size. My app places a fisheye distortion on the bitmap from touchevents. it then creates a subset bitmap of the original, sends it for processing then places it over the original bitmap as an overlay in the correct position from the xy coords from touch event. so i need the bitmap to be the same size as the screen on each phone's camera

Comment: You can set the preview and capture size via camera parameters, but you can only set them to what the camera supports (you can get a list from the camera class, again see link above) but if all you are doing is distorting the image via touch inputs then it sounds like you are just need to get the preview size closest to the display size (most mfg have one that matches closely) then scale the resulting image to that size if you don't want to map your touch events to a larger or smaller image