# How to reduce the image pixels in android but not the size?

Tags: java, android

After capturing an image from starting of default camera via `Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)`, I want to reduce the resolution (pixels) of the image. I know that image quality will get disturbed but no worries to me.

While searching in JAVA, we can use JAI (`JAVA ADVANCED IMAGING API`) library to do the required job. Actually I'm not aware about using of this library. Basically I want to store, send and want to process on that image, that's why I want reduce pixels from the image.

Any suggestion guys.. Valuable help appreciated...

Comment: take a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507771/setting-camera-image-size-in-android)

Comment: How we can achieve our goal after capturing an image from camera, There should not be any worries for size and resolution while capturing an image. I'm worry about after capturing an image how I can manage to reduce pixels and the file size of an image without being affected on height and width...