# Why does image go blur?

Tags: android, image, android-camera

I'm trying to develop an app that uses camera API of android. But when i take image using app image goes blurred.

Image using google camera app :

[image]

Image using my camera app :

[image]

camera parameters part :

```
Camera.Parameters param;
param = camera.getParameters();
param.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_FIXED);
param.setPictureFormat(ImageFormat.JPEG);
param.setJpegQuality(100);
camera.setParameters(param);
camera.startPreview();
```

Picture callback part :

```
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        camera.release();
        preview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            Log.d("PictureCall",
                    "Error creating media file, check storage permissions");
            return;
        }

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("File Excep :", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("File Excep :", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5163778/3330969.

Comment: Are you storing a PREVIEW image?

Comment: I tried this already but it's not working.

Comment: @Stan yes i stored the image

Answer (score 1):

```
 Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
 List<Camera.Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPictureSizes();
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (size.width > w || size.height > h) {
                    w = size.width;
                    h = size.height;
                }
            }
            parameters.setPictureSize(w, h);
```

Comment: add this code into ur surface changed method for set parameter

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
private static final int CAMERA_PICTURE = 3333;
Uri selectedImageUri;
```

on your camera btn do this

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PICTURE);
```

and on your onActivityResult write this code

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode==CAMERA_PICTURE ) {
             selectedImageUri = data.getData();

             if(selectedImageUri!=null){

        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri));
       //perform operations with your bitmap here 
                }
           }
       }
    }
```

This method will give you a full resolution image rather than thumbnail or blurry image.
Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for this but i have to use android camera api in my code.

Answer (score 0):

comment your camera jpeg quality:

```
param.setJpegQuality(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to force an output image resolution on your picture capture by querying supported sizes with [`params.getSupportedPictureSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes()), choosing the biggest one and then setting it [`params.setPictureSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)) when you are setting your camera parameters in the posted code, though I would find it weird that the default resolution would be so small as the sample you have posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`setPictureSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int,%20int)) [`setPreviewSize()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int,%20int)) methods, and set best picture size & preview size available from [`getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()).

**Check code of below method (from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605560/how-do-you-take-high-resolution-images-using-camera-takepicture/10605793#26686355))**:

```
     /**
     * Set Camera parameters for Best image quality available
     *
     * @param mCamera Camera object
     */
    public void setCameraParameters(Camera mCamera) {
        Camera.Parameters mCameraParams;

        // Set Camera Parameters for best image quality available
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCameraParams = mCamera.getParameters();

            Camera.Size bestSizeAvailable = null;
            List<Camera.Size> listPreviewSizes = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
            bestSizeAvailable = listPreviewSizes.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < listPreviewSizes.size(); i++) {
                if ((listPreviewSizes.get(i).width * listPreviewSizes.get(i).height) > (bestSizeAvailable.width * bestSizeAvailable.height)) {
                    bestSizeAvailable = listPreviewSizes.get(i);
                }
            }

            List<Integer> listSupportedPreviewFormats = mCameraParams.getSupportedPreviewFormats();
            Iterator<Integer> iteratorSupportedPreviewFormats = listSupportedPreviewFormats.iterator();
            while (iteratorSupportedPreviewFormats.hasNext()) {
                Integer previewFormat = iteratorSupportedPreviewFormats.next();
                if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12) {
                    mCameraParams.setPreviewFormat(previewFormat);
                }
            }

            mCameraParams.setPreviewSize(bestSizeAvailable.width, bestSizeAvailable.height);
            mCameraParams.setPictureSize(bestSizeAvailable.width, bestSizeAvailable.height);
            mCamera.setParameters(mCameraParams);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    }
```